# Finding a system of linear equations (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a system of linear equations whose solution set is the line in the 3 dimensional space.

$$  \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\  \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} t-4 \\ t-10 \\ 2t-20 \\  \end{pmatrix}$$

What i tried

The question is asking to link the variables $x$ $y$ and $z$ into a single equation while removing the $t$. I first equate $x=t-4$,$y=t-10$ and $z=2t-20$. Then i tried combining the equations to form $$x=y+6$$ and $$z=2x-12$$ and $$z=2y$$. However i could not combine all these 3 variable into a single equation. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: You would need two such equations as you have, since each only determines a plane, and a line is the intersection of two planes. [That may be why it says find a *system*.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of the system depends on one parameter ($t$), considering that you have a 3 dimensional space, your system of equations will be defined by a 3x3 matrix and using [Rouché's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem) you know that the range of that matrix must be 2.

That means that you need 2 equations to get the solution that you are looking for.

In your case, one possible system (as you got) would be:

$$x - y =6 $$

$$z - 2y = 0 $$

Using matrix notation, this is equivalent to:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0  \\ 
0 & -2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
x  \\ 
y  \\
z 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
6 \\ 
0  \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}$$